# PySpark dependency management approach

Tags: python, pyspark, dependency-management

Could you please explain me pros and cons of the following approaches for distributing spark code to spark workers

1. [This approach](https://developerzen.com/best-practices-writing-production-grade-pyspark-jobs-cb688ac4d20f). Add `--py-files jobs.zip,libs.zip` to your spark-submit command. Where `jobs.zip` is just your zipped .py files, while `libs.zip` is .py files of dependencies build with `pip install -r requirements`
2. [This approach](https://bytes.grubhub.com/managing-dependencies-and-artifacts-in-pyspark-7641aa89ddb7). Add `--py-files jobs.whl,dep1.whl,dep2.whl,...` to your spark-submit command. Like the first approach, but instead of zip you have wheel files, and instead of two files you have as many files as dependencies. Wheel files are built with `pip wheel -r requirements.txt`. You can than built list of wheel files dynamically in submit script.

What benefits you get from using the second approach over the first one? Is there any third option better than the first two?